# Getting IDs of added documents after import operation is complete

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler

I'm trying to setup a Solr dataimport.EventListener to call a SOAP service with the IDs of the documents which have been added in the update event. I have a class which implements org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.EventListener and I *thought* that the result of getAllEntityFields() would yield a collection of document IDs. Unfortunately, the result of the method yields an empty list. Even more confusing is that context.getSolrCore().getName() yields an empty string rather than the actual core name. So it seems I am not quite on the right path here.

The current setup is the following:
Whenever a certain sproc is called in SQL, it puts a message in a queue. This queue has a listener on it which initiates a program which reads the queue and calls other sprocs. After the sprocs are complete, a delta or full import operation is performed on Solr. Immediately after, a method is called to update a cache. However, because the import operation on Solr may not have yet been completed before this update method is called the cache may be updated with "stale" data.

I was hoping to use a dataimport EventListener to call the method which updates the cache since my other options seem far too complex (e.g. polling the dataimport URL to determine when to call the update method or using a queue to list document IDs which need to be updated and have the EventListener call a method on a service to receive this queue and update the cache). I'm having a bit of a hard time finding documentation or examples. Does anyone have any ideas on how I should approach the problem?

Answer (score 2):

From what i understand, you are trying to update your cache as and when the documents are added. Depending on what version of solr you are running, you can do one of the following.

Solr 4.0 provides script transformer that lets you do this.
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#ScriptTransformer

With prior versions of solr, you can chain one handler on top of other as answered in the following post.
[Solr and custom update handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593887/solr-and-custom-update-handler/9936315#9936315)

Comment: I'm not really following how a script transformer would help in this case. It seems to run before indexing, and I need to run the cache update mechanism after indexing is completed. Is my understanding correct? A custom update handler might be what I need, though. I'll look into it.

Comment: Actually, now I'm not so sure. Seems like a script transformer is useful during indexing, which doesn't seem to be helpful in this scenario. The custom update handler sounded interesting, but I'm not using the update method to manage documents in Solr. Everything is behind handled via the Data Import Handler using either full or delta-imports. So I'm feeling rather stuck again.

Comment: Well, are you aware that indexing doesnt really take effect until a commit is done? Can you use that fact to your advantage? i.e, do a full import with commit=false, then update your cache and do a commit

Comment: If I'm understanding commits correctly, the data is stored in Solr, but it is not yet indexed. Meaning that you cannot query against it. Is that correct?

If it is, then the way the system is currently setup I cannot use a non-committed update to my advantage because the cache which needs to be updated queries Solr.


It seems right now, the best course of action would be to use something (e.g. queue in SQL) to store the record IDs which need to be updated then have Solr signal that an update is finished which will then trigger a cache update program which will receive the queue and query Solr

Comment: i'm looking for answer to this same question